# Typo in flagging suggestions - "not a real question"

Tags: bug, status-completed, flagging

From the flagging summary:

> It's difficult to tell what is being asked here. This question is ambiguous, vague, incomplete, **overy** broad, or rhetorical and cannot be reasonably answered in its current form.

Comment: I've contacted a community moderator who will tell the dev team. Thanks!

Comment: I wonder how long this has been wrong - I can't imagine it's been longer than since the recent change to the migration options.

Answer (score 5):

Looks like I picked the wrong day to be overy excited about updating close reasons.

Comment: Touché, sir.  Out of curiosity, did we get new text on any of them?  Nothing's jumping out at me as different.

Answer (score 0):

The Community Team and the developers are aware of this issue. I received word moments ago that it is being worked on. :)

...And it should be fixed now!